# can I still list deleted blob if "blob soft delete" is disabled

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have azure blob storage, see screen shot for its confiugration;
i can not find documentation, whether i can still list the deleted blob if soft delete is disabled.

I tried to use portal or library (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/).

[image: try to list deleted blob]
[image: current configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If Soft Delete is disabled on the account, when you perform delete action on the blob, it is permanently deleted. It will not appear in the blob listing.

From the documentation [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob?tabs=azure-ad#soft-delete-feature-disabled):

> When a blob is successfully deleted, it's immediately removed from the
> storage account's index, and it's no longer accessible to clients. The
> blob's data is later removed from the service during garbage
> collection.

Answer (score -1):

Soft delete is a feature designed to retain deleted data for a specified retention period. Without soft delete, when a blob is deleted, it is permanently removed. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-overview#how-blob-soft-delete-works)

please note that if the soft delete was disabled after storing the blobs, you can access the deleted blobs until the retention period has elapsed.

If the soft delete is already disabled before storing the blobs, the blobs can't be listed